# 怎么朗读“∶”号在这句话里？how should ":" be read aloud here?

Tags: pronunciation

怎么朗读“∶”号在这句话里？
《6∶2的比值是3》

须要读冒(mào)吗？

看到这句话在现代汉语规范词典里：

> 比值
> bǐzhí
> 名 两数相比得出的数值, 如6∶2的比值是3。
> (也说比率。)

How should ":" be read aloud in the dictionary entry above?

Comment: 正常來說，6:2讀作「六比二」。

Comment: One more thing, 冒 should be pronounced as `mào` instead of `máo`.

Comment: Yes thanks @Alan zzz, indeed! I'll fix this.

Comment: Actually, they are different, [易混标点：冒号比号](https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/85282212#:~:text=%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87%EF%BC%88%E5%85%A8%E8%A7%92%EF%BC%89%E5%86%92%E5%8F%B7%E6%98%AF%E2%80%9C,%E5%8A%9F%E8%83%BD%EF%BC%8C%E6%B3%A8%E6%84%8F%E4%B8%8D%E8%A6%81%E8%AF%AF%E7%94%A8%E3%80%82)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 6∶2的比值是3

It reads as: 六比二的比值是三.

":" reads as 比.